# Greek data response not visible in express

Tags: express, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I am trying to receive data from an external API which contains data in Greek language from my express backend however when I print the response I only see � instead of the Greek letters. I have tried sending different charsets in the API call but to no avail.
Is there something I am missing? I don't have any experience in handling different languages

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the response headers and found out that it was using `windows-1253` encoding so I used a library [windows-1253](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-1253) to decode the response.

My bad I didn't thought of looking at the response headers earlier